# Can't get woocommerce_get_price_html to work

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I'm building a function to interact with the price html block in wordpress. This is my code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', array( $this, 'get_price_html' ));    
public function get_price_html( $product )
{
    echo '<a href="my-price">' . $product->get_price() . '</a>';
}
```

It's not working. What's wrong?

Comment: there is no actual question here

Comment: sorry I forgot it :D but I placed it in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are missing parameters (even if you're not using those) as per its [definition](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Grouped.html#128) and always try to `return` into filters instead of `echo` the value. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', array( $this, 'get_price_html' ), 10, 2);    
public function get_price_html( $price_html, $product )
{
    return '<a href="my-price">' . $product->get_price() . '</a>';
}
```